# Oracle sp's list - latest updated?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to run a query in Oracle pl SQL that will tell me which SP's have been updated most recently. In SQL Server it would be this:

```
select name, modify_date 
from sys.procedures 
order by modify_date desc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this query :

```
select *  from user_objects 
where object_type = 'PROCEDURE'
ORDER BY LAST_DDL_TIME DESC
```

You may also want to use this table to see all procedures : `all_objects`

Answer (score 2):

Query the [`dba_objects`](http://ss64.com/orad/DBA_OBJECTS.html) table:

```
SELECT object_name, last_ddl_time
FROM dba_objects
WHERE object_type = 'PROCEDURE'
ORDER BY last_ddl_time DESC
```

Comment: I ran this Joao, but it gives only 34 rows and also they are from year 2006. I wanted to see the most recent updated ones for past 2 weeks.

Comment: Are you sure that you are only looking for procedures, there are packages and functions as well.

Comment: Note that the `last_ddl_time` is the last time that any DDL was executed against the procedure, not just DDL that modified the procedure.  So, for example, if you `GRANT` a user access to a stored procedure, the `last_ddl_time` will be updated even though the procedure itself was not modified.